# How to get a percentage of a timedelta in python

Tags: python, datetime, operators

I have two datetime objects witch gave me a timedelta (time01 - time02).

I want to get a specific timedelta, witch is 6% of the previous timedelta. Is there a proper way to do it ?

Here is what I tried and the output :

```
import datetime

sunrise = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)
sunset = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)
sunTime = datetime.timedelta(hours=sunset.hour-sunrise.hour, minutes=sunset.minute-sunrise.minute, seconds=sunset.second-sunrise.second)

...

print sunrise-datetime.timedelta(sunTime*0.06)
```

Output :

```
sunrise - datetime.timedelta(sunTime*0.06):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'
```

Thanks !

Comment: `timedelta` doesnt support multiplying by floats but it does support multiplying and dividing by ints which means that you can multiply by 6 and divide by 100 to achieve the same effect.

Comment: just use the timestamps to get the delta in seconds then multiply by .06 and make integer apply that as timedelta seconds to .fromtimestamp of sunrise timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
sunrise = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)
sunset = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)
sunTime = sunset-sunrise

...

print sunrise-datetime.timedelta(seconds=sunTime.total_seconds()*0.06)
```

Comment: Works provided that `sunTime.days == 0` and either `sunTime.microSeconds == 0` or else that we don't care about that much accuracy. The first is a given considering how `sunTime` was actually generated.

Comment: Did not know that Steve. Thanks!

Comment: and you can use `timedelta.total_seconds()` to avoid these problems :-)

Comment: edited my answer in case anyone should use it. Yay, for learning!

Comment: So now it can work in the (ant)arctic circle, where sunset - sunrise might be 6 months ;-)

Comment: Perhaps someone would use it for sunset-sunrise on other planets! Venus takes 243 earth-days to do a full rotation! :)

Comment: Thanks ! It helps a lot ! By the way, the time beetwen the beginig of a day (dawn) and the sunrise is ~6% of the sunTime of the day (sunset - sunrise) ! and idem for the time beetwen the sunset and the end of the day (dusk) ! Now you know ... ^^

Answer (score 0):

timestamps are in seconds so this should work

```
import datetime

sunrise = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*sunrise timestamp*/)
offset = int((/* sunset timestamp */ - /* sunrise timestamp */) * .06)

print sunrise-datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
```

Comment: It's a good option, but I was looking for something more ... "Object-friendly" (like `result = timeObject*0.06` ) ... Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating timedelta you could manipulate the input to timedelta for example

```
import datetime

percent = 0.06    
sunrise = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)
sunset = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(/*a timestamp*/)

sunTime = datetime.timedelta(hours=(sunset.hour-sunrise.hour)*percent,
                             minutes=(sunset.minute-sunrise.minute)*percent,
                             seconds=(sunset.second-sunrise.second)*percent)
print sunTime
```

Achieves the same effect and you only create one timedelta object.

Comment: Yeah, I through about that one but I was looking for a more "proper" way for doing this ... more "Object-friendly" (something in the line of `result = timeObject*0.06` ) ... Thanks anyway !